# SSRS 2012 - Using Boolean Parameter to Declare Column Visibility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a Boolean parameter named "ShowHours" that if set to true it shows all rows, but if set to false, I want it to hide the rows.

This works okay, but the thing is that I only want rows that have a 0 on the column named "Total Hours" to be hidden when set to false; every other row should still be visible. I am using the visibly expression `=Not(Parameters!ShowHours.Value)` but it does not seem to work since it hides all rows, and I only want it to hide rows that have 0. Does anyone know what expression I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using in the `Hidden` property:

```
=IIF(fields!TotalHours.Value = 0 and Not Parameters!ShowHours.Value, True, False )
```

If TotalHours is a sum calculation:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Hours.Value) = 0 and Not Parameters!ShowHours.Value, True, False )
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, and yes I did use a sum so your second expression worked the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like this:

```
=IIf(Parameters!ShowHours.Value = false And Fields!Total_Hours.Value = 0, true, false)
```

In other words, if the parameter is set to hide and the value is 0 then it will be hidden.

Comment: Yes, the AND item, how did I not think of that? I got it to work thanks, but you got it backwards